# mobile to mobile TCP socket connection

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, tcp

Reading among the list of possibilities of the Java ME platform, its possible for a J2ME app running on a mobile to initiate a TCP Socket or HTTP connection with a server.
On similar lines, Is it possible to form a TCP socket connection between two mobile phones?

Comment: how do you plan on communicating non-static IP addresses between phones so the initial connection can be established?

Comment: @ QROS - I don't know really, and the matter isn't resolved yet.

Comment: For initiating the connection you can use sms. I know one application (http://www.mobilerise.com/) does it that way. When you want to connect you enter the phone number of the other person and it sends your connection information to the other side as an sms. Other application should be already running or at least registered for certains sms's using PushRegistry I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a [ServerSocketConnection](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/ServerSocketConnection.html) and a [SocketConnection](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/SocketConnection.html) on the other side. This allow two way direct communication between two mobile phones. You can look at [this page](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/midp2network/) for some more details. But I am not sure about the security requirements and what is allowed and what is not using these classes.

Answer (score -1):

Not if the server phone is running a J2ME app; J2ME does not support socket server connections.  Also beware that many mobile operators do not allow socket server connections to be made on their networks.

Comment: JSR118 specifies an Interface ServerSocketConnection, you could find more info at http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/